# generate large range function from smaller

Tags: functions, special-functions

i lies between 0 to 31, with equal probability (1/32).

k is either 0 or 1.(equal probability 1/2)

How can one generate i using only k?

Comment: We can toss a fair coin $5$ times, heads $0$ tails $1$ and treat the result as a binary representation of $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Flip $k$ five times and delete any case in which $k = 1,1,1,1,1$.

Comment: if i=32,simply include the case k=1,1,1,1,1?

Comment: Yes.  The binary representation of $n$.